# How to convert any numbers to numpy nan

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I tried to assign numpy.nan to some numbers, but not able to do that.
For example:

```
data = np.arange(10)
data[data>=5]=np.nan
```

and the error I got is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-7acc9ad5a8af> in <module>
      1 data = np.arange(10)
----> 2 data[data>=5]=np.nan

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.nan` is considered a `float`, and therefore cannot be assigned to a list of `integers`.

You have multiple options, which I will make a non-exhaustive list below. **I recommend the 3rd option since it is the safest, and probably the fastest.**

1. Cast your `integers array` as `floating point array`

```py
data = np.arange(10).astype('float')
data[data >= 5] = np.nan
data
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

2. Immediatly ask numpy to create a `floating point array`

```py
data = np.arange(10.)
data[data >= 5] = np.nan
data
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

3. Specifically ask for 'floating point' numbers using `dtype` parameters

```py
data = np.arange(10, dtype='float')
data[data >= 5] = np.nan
data
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently created an integer array. Converting it to floats, will resolve the error:

```
data = np.arange(10).astype(np.float)
data[data>=5] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without converting by using numpy.where:

```
data = numpy.arange(10)
data = numpy.where(data>5, data, numpy.nan)
```